# Fast solution to unidentified citations and references

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I'm working on a medium size document, with lots of citations and cross references (Latex inserts ?? where it can not find the citation or crossed reference). What is the way to find the unidentified references through latex and its generated files?

Comment: What do you mean by "unidentified references"? Do you mean labels that are referred to, but not defined?

Comment: @mafp The missing/misspelled citation keywords (\cite{keyword}) or reference keywords (\ref{...}). Latex inserts ?? where it can not find the citations and crossed references.

Comment: Texmaker( but I assume all editors) give a warning for unidentified references, something like: citations "[name here]" on page [#] unidentified. This is not sufficient?

Comment: Did you run bibtex before running LaTeX?

Answer (score 11):

Most LaTeX editors will provide you with a point-and-click feature to find such missing references, but the output of `pdflatex` will already tell you: You will see things like:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `key' on page 1 undefined on input line 42.
```

and

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `label' on page 1 undefined on input line 42.
```

Those same warnings can be found in the `log` file of your document. E.g., by doing

```
grep "LaTeX Warning" mydoc.log
```

you will find

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `key' on page 1 undefined on input line 42.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lab' on page 1 undefined on input line 42.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```